# Cascading Visibility in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using v-for to display a series of four identical form inputs - one set of inputs for each 'Job' in my 'jobs' data element:

```
data: {
    "jobs": [
        {
        "jobType": "First Job",
        "jobName": "",
        "jobSalary": 0,
        },
        {
        "jobType": "Second Job",
        "jobName": "",
        "jobSalary": 0,
        },
        {
        "jobType": "Third Job",
        "jobName": "",
        "jobSalary": 0,
        },
        {
        "jobType": "Fourth Job",
        "jobName": "",
        "jobSalary": 0,
        }
        ]
  }

<div id="app">
<div v-for="(theJob, index) in jobs" :id="'JobSelector'+index">
        <h4>{{ theJob.jobType }}</h4>
        <input type="text" :id="'jobName'+index" list="jobSelection" placeholder="Job Name" v-model="theJob.jobName" @change="handleJobChange(theJob, index)">
        <input type="number" min="0" step="1000" :id="'jobSalary'+index" placeholder="Salary" v-model="theJob.jobSalary">
</div>

<datalist id="jobSelection">
  <option>Doctor</option>
  <option>Lawyer</option>
  <option>Data Scientist</option>
  <option>Firefighter</option>
  <option>Journalist</option>
  <option>Programmer</option>
  <option>Artist</option>
  <option>Police Officer</option>
</datalist>

</div>
```

What I would like is for only the first set of fields to be visible when the page loads. Each subsequent set would appear only after @handleJobChange detects that the previous field has been filled out.

Further, if the user blanks out the first field, each subsequent field should hide itself.

The general rule is: If THIS text field is blank, all the elements after it should be hidden.

I've messed around with v-show and v-if, but how do I set a boolean that meets these conditions?

I know it's bad practice to directly manipulate DOM elements in Vue, but I can't figure out how to do this without resorting to traversal with 'parentElement.nextElementSibling' etc.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e23L181g/

Comment: Hey there, this is not the best solution but can you try this? https://jsfiddle.net/e23L181g/16/

Comment: Hey, another solution : https://jsfiddle.net/e23L181g/20/

Comment: @IndrajeetLatthe in your solution you have a little bug ; you have to init jobName of the hidden job

Comment: @Mgasmi Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a new array that contain the showed jobs and i updated handleJobChange and zeroOutJob  
html :

```
<div v-for="(theJob, index) in jobs" :id="'JobSelector'+index" v-show="index in showedJobs">
```

method :

```
handleJobChange(theJob, index) {
            if(event.currentTarget.value == "") {//If this job field is blank
                //Make everything after it invisible
                    this.zeroOutJob(index);//Remove subsequent entries
            } else { //If this job field contains text
                //Unhide the following job selector
              this.showedJobs.push(index+1);
            }
        },
        zeroOutJob(index) {//Delete all class information
            var jb = this.jobs[index];
            for(var i = index+1;i<this.jobs.length;i++){
              this.jobs[i].jobName = "";
              this.jobs[i].jobSalary = 0;
            }
            this.showedJobs.splice(index+1,this.showedJobs.length)
        }
```

jsfiddle link for this solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/e23L181g/22/